# Pyqt5 ошибка при запуске

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5

Выдает ошибку:

```
File "main.py", line 10, in __init__
self.menubar = QMainWindow.menuBar()
TypeError: menuBar(self): first argument of unbound method must have type 'QMainWindow'
```

Как исправить ?

---

```
import sys
import PyQt5
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QDesktopWidget, QMainWindow, QAction, qApp
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon

HEIGHT = 800
WIDTH = 1300
class Menu():
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow().__init__()
        self.menubar = QMainWindow().menuBar()
        self.file = self.menubar.addMenu('&File')

        self.exitAction = QAction(QIcon('exit.png'), '&Exit', self)
        self.exitAction.setShortcut('Ctrl+Q')
        self.exitAction.setStatusTip('Exit application')
        self.exitAction.triggered.connect(self.close)

        self.file.addAction(self.exitAction)


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        q = QDesktopWidget().availableGeometry()
        r_w, r_h = q.width(), q.height()
        self.setGeometry(r_w/2-WIDTH/2, r_h/2-HEIGHT/2, WIDTH, HEIGHT)
        self.setFixedSize(1300, 800)
        self.setWindowTitle('Lings')
        self.setWindowIcon(QIcon('Lings.ico'))
        menu = Menu()
        self.show()


# class Window1(QMainWindow):
#   def __init__(self):
#       super().__init__()
#   def initUI(self):
#       mainWindow.menu()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    mainWindow = MainWindow()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Добро пожаловать, Injustive. Чтобы получать быстрые и правильные ответы, всегда предоставляйте свой примет в обычном текстовом виде. Нам его надо скопировать и получить ту ошибку, о которой вы пишите. Скрины текстов программ НЕ ПУБЛИКУЙТЕ, их вряд ли будут смотреть. Отредактируйте свой вопрос.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как вариант:

```
import sys
import PyQt5
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QDesktopWidget, QMainWindow, QAction, qApp
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon

HEIGHT = 800
WIDTH = 1300

class Menu(QWidget):                                                    # + QWidget   
    def __init__(self, parent=None):                                    # + parent
        super().__init__(parent)                                        # + parent

#        self.menubar = QMainWindow().menuBar()
        self.menubar = parent.menuBar()                                 # +++
        self.file = self.menubar.addMenu('&File')

        self.exitAction = QAction(QIcon('exit.png'), '&Exit', self)
        self.exitAction.setShortcut('Ctrl+Q')
        self.exitAction.setStatusTip('Exit application')
#        self.exitAction.triggered.connect(self.close)
        self.exitAction.triggered.connect(parent.close)                 # +++

        self.file.addAction(self.exitAction)


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
#        q = QDesktopWidget().availableGeometry()
#        r_w, r_h = q.width(), q.height()
#        print(r_w, r_h)
#        self.setGeometry(r_w/2-WIDTH/2, r_h/2-HEIGHT/2, WIDTH, HEIGHT)   # ???
#        print(self.geometry())                                         
#        self.setFixedSize(1300, 800)
        self.resize(WIDTH, HEIGHT)                                        # +

        self.setWindowTitle('Lings')
        self.setWindowIcon(QIcon('Lings.ico'))

        self.menu = Menu(self)                                            # + self

#        self.show()



if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    mainWindow = MainWindow()
    mainWindow.show()                                                   # +
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Да, работает, спасибо!